# HTML table width in UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I am dynamically generating HTML and feeding it into a UIWebView.  I have a few tables of data displaying and I can't get them to stretch the full width of the screen.

So far I have tried...

- 100% width attribute on table
- 100% width style on table
- widths on all cells adding up to 100%
- style in head applying 100% width to all tables (and * sub elements)

I have also tried XHTML 4.01 and HTML 5 doctypes in case that might be causing display issues.  Here is what it current looks like...

[unfortunately I am a noob and can't post pictures yet]

I simply want them to fill all the space inside the 1px keyline surrounding the tables.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured it out.
Because I was building the HTML dynamically (appending to an `NSMutableString`), my percent sign was being treated as a format specifier and was disregarded.

I had to escape with a second percent sign and everything is working.

```
<table style=\"width:100%%;\">...
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Then, in that case, copy the comment, post it as an answer and select the answer, as the accepted answer.

Comment: Copied OP's answer from comment above.

Comment: Thanks Brock.  I wasn't able to answer my own question for two days - was going to wait it out... appreciate the revision.

Answer (score 0):

```
width: 100%;
```

That should really work...

Else, try to add "!important" to the "width" attribute in CSS:

```
width: 100% !important;
```

Comment: I have tried that and every other variation I can think of.  For some reason the table cells only match the width of the text that is within them.  I thought it might be a float issue, no.  Conflicting style issue, no.  I literally just coded in a table with one cell at the very top of my page and it doesn't stretch.  I am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no" />
```

to your  section. (`device-width` is meant to be the width of your device screen according to the orientation).